# WPF login to ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wpf

I'm currently working with a asp.net MVC5 project. But I had a fun Idea I would made a WPF application aswell. And with this WPF application I would like to login with the login info I have on my asp.net site. I do know how to link the database to my WPF application how ever, after doing this I am stuck and I would appricate some help.

Comment: Not nearly enough information as to what the issue is. If you know how to link a DB then why wouldn't you be able to login?

Comment: I would assume I have to login form onto WPF and send it to you MVC website, the server verifies them and if the credentials are correctly it emits an authentication cookie which is sent back to the client. The client stores this cookie for further authentication.

So this means I will need to send a POST request to the MVC website that verifies the username and password, then the server returns a cookie which is stored by the client in a CookieContainer.

Comment: So again, if you know the theory behind this, what point are you struggling with?

Comment: @DanielCasserly there's a big difference between theory and implementation, which is why it's a bad idea to create your own authentication services - what if someone intercepts the call or fakes it?  ASP.NET already provides Client Application services for this purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already provided by the [ASP.NET Client Application Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384339(v=vs.140).aspx), which expose ASP.NET services like membership, profile etc as services to other applications. Authentication is specifically addressed in [How to: Implement User Login with Client Application Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384313(v=vs.110).aspx) with a full walkthrough in [Walkthrough: Using Client Application Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546195(v=vs.110).aspx).

A far better solution though would be to use Windows Authentication, if the WPF client and IIS servers are in the same domain. This way you wouldn't need to do anything on the client side, and only have to enable Windows Authentication on the server side.

Comment: I can't find any updated resources on "ASP.NET Client Application Services". Most of the examples are showing how to do it with ASP.NET Framework 3.5 and not a single example with the new Identity framework. If I hope you can update your answer with an up-to-date solution or refer to a good article about that